# sitemap URL without trailing slash 404 error

Tags: wordpress, slash, trailing, sitemap.xml

I have wordpress website that I installed google XML Plugin.
all urls with and without trailing slash works properly.
but for sitemap.xml without trailing slash browser return 404 error.
I modified permalinks, .htaccess ,... but it doesn't work.

https://pteceng.com/partners/deltav  =>OK

https://pteceng.com/partners/deltav/ =>OK

https://pteceng.com/sitemap.xml/ =>OK

https://pteceng.com/sitemap.xml  =>NOT OK

Comment: Make sure that you are having sitemap.xml file in root directory, i doubt you are forgetting it. If file is there then slash won't be required.